# Load a library file on to a config/file.php

Tags: codeigniter

On my **config/config_setting.php** I need to be able to load my library file **libraries/settings.php** on to it, and the be able to use the get function like below.

I would like to be able to do `$config['encryption_key'] = $this->settings->get('encryption_key');`

What do I need to do to make library work in a config file?

```
<?php

require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/Setting.php';

$config['encryption_key'] = $this->settings->get('encryption_key');
```

When refresh page it shows error **Undefined property: MX_Config::$setting**

Comment: You wouldn't load the library directly into a config file. You would do it at runtime, like I show below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MYLibrary
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function loadSettings($custom=null)
    {
        $settings = array();

        if(is_null($custom))
        {
            // Grab the default config file if no custom one is set
            // application/config/config
            $settings = $this->config->config;
        }
        else
        {
            // Load a custom settings configuration
            // application/config/custom
            $settings = $this->load->config($custom);
        }

        $this->load->model('settings_model');

        $rows = $this->settings_model->getAllRows();

        if(!$rows) return;

        foreach($rows as $k => $v){
            if(array_key_exists($k, $settings)){
                $this->config->set_item($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    public function __get($object)
    {
        $instance =&get_instance();
        return $instance->$object;
    }
}
```

--

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('MYLibrary');
        $this->mylibrary->loadSettings();

    }
}
```

Personally I would create a Hook instead of a loading a library inside MY_Controllers constructor. You can simple create a `$hook['pre_controller']` and paste in your library stuff. That way it will get load before any constructors.

Comment: @Phillip I tried it but now got dynamic way. Thanks for help. My add answer seems to work no issues. Just have to make sure names set in database table encryption_key

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error works this way dynamic config file now.

**Name: config/config_setting.php**

```
<?php

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );

$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('table');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
   $config[ $row->item ] = $row->value;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You really should keep any logic outside of any configuration files. Configurations files should just hold data.